# Running external program

Tags: java

What's the difference between running programs using java and run it using the command line? In the first case it does not work, but in the second case it works fine.

Java:

```
try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime.exec("../../../my/prog \"//10.124.12.15/C:/output/*\" ../../../input/345 -N -A");
    DataInputStream bis = new DataInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
    int _byte;
    while ((_byte = bis.read()) != -1)
        System.out.print((char)_byte);
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

AND command:

```
../../../my/prog "//10.124.12.15/C:/output/*" ../../../input/345 -N -A
```

Comment: Maybe path is wrong. Why don't you call the program using absolute paths?

Comment: Besides the good advice already offered, be sure to implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: Is this a permissions problem? Are you running the program in another user context, such as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I solved my problem:

```
try {
    String cmd="/progs/my/prog //10.124.12.15/C:/output/* /temp/input/345 -N -A" 
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime.exec(
       new String[]{"/usr/bin/bash", "-c", cmd, "1>/dev/null 2>&1"});    
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using absolute path. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Program runs (output messages are printed), but it doesn't fulfill its mission - doesn't copy files.